# Postgres deadlock exception is not being caught in the exception blocks

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, spring-jdbc

I have a service layer which would create indexes

```java
    try {
        for(String fieldName : fieldNames) {
            daoLayer.createIndex(tableName, fieldName);   
            indexCounter++;
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Exception while creating index", e);
    }

}
```

My dao layer is where I get the actual postgres template and the execute the index creation statement.

```java
public void createIndex(String table, String column) {
    // some validations
    String indexName = getIndexName(table, column);
    String query = "create index concurrently if not exists" + " " + indexName + " " + "on" + " " + table + "(" + column + ");";
    getJDBCTemplate.execute(query);
}
```

I replicated a **dead lock scenario** by prallelly running queries from code and terminal on same table

Once both queries are running.. as expected i got a dead lock in debug log. But the exception is not caught in neither of the catch blocks. It's just printing the stack trace and moving onto to 
increment the **indexCounter**.

```
org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: StatementCallback; SQL [CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS test_index ON customers(email);]; ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 5006 waits for ShareLock on virtual transaction 37/6293032; blocked by process 5625.
Process 5625 waits for ShareLock on relation 1311173147 of database 1310910579; blocked by process 5006.
  Hint: See server log for query details.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 5006 waits for ShareLock on virtual transaction 37/6293032; blocked by process 5625.
Process 5625 waits for ShareLock on relation 1311173147 of database 1310910579; blocked by process 5006.
  Hint: See server log for query details.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:419)
    at com.companyXYZ.database.JdbcTemplateImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1e119f19.CGLIB$execute$10(<generated>)
    at com.companyXYZ.db.JdbcTemplateImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1e119f19$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a0de82c2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at com.companyXYZ.db.RetryMethodInterceptor.invokeSuper(RetryMethodInterceptor.java:34)
    at com.companyXYZ.db.RetryMethodInterceptor.intercept(RetryMethodInterceptor.java:23)
    at com.companyXYZ.db.JdbcTemplateImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1e119f19.execute(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:445)
    at com.companyXYZ.db.JdbcTemplateImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1e119f19.CGLIB$execute$9(<generated>)
    at com.companyXYZ.db.JdbcTemplateImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1e119f19$$FastClassByCGLIB$$a0de82c2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
```

Why the exception is not being caught in the catch blocks ?

Comment: Probably because of `RetryMethodInterceptor` which catches it before you get a chance.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman. RetryMethodInterceptor is the culprit.